# Silverlight TextBlock Visibility property inital value before binding is applied

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

I Have a TextBlock on Silverlight Page.

XAML

```
 <TextBlock Text="*"  x:Name="HasChangesTextBlock" Foreground="Red" FontSize="14" Visibility="{Binding Path=HasChanges, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                           Margin="5,0,0,0">

 </TextBlock>
```

Page loading takes few moments. And before binding is applied I want  TextBlock to be collapsed, but default value of Visibility Property is Visible.

Is there way to make TextBlock to be collapsed before binding is applied?

Answer (score 8):

I found the solution.

we should just add    **FallbackValue=Collapsed** to the binding expression

That is a breaking change that was introduced in Silverlight 4.

XAML

```
   <TextBlock Text="*"  x:Name="HasPlayListChangesTextBlock" Foreground="Red" FontSize="14" 
                               Visibility="{Binding Path=HasChanges, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter},FallbackValue=Collapsed}">

   </TextBlock>
```

Comment: In what way is this change a "breaking change"?  Its just an improvement in SL4 I don't see how this change breaks any existing code?

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you. I agree with AnthonyWJones though that this isn't a "breaking change".

Answer (score 0):

How about in the constructor of the page, after you've called InitalizeComponent()? Something like this:

```
public MyClass() 
{
  InitalizeComponent();
  HasChangesTextBlock.Visibility = Visiblility.Collapsed;
}
```

Comment: if we do like that, than binding won't work, cause it will be erased by the new value.